# How to get started with ReactJS Hello World example?

Tags: reactjs

I am using MacBook Pro.

I prefer to use ubuntu in a VM for web development.

I created a index.html inside my Macbook and then simply open it with Chrome.

The html was created following this [video](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-hello-world-first-component#post-370)

and this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name=description content="">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>First Component</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0-beta.1/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0-beta.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/jsx">
    /** @jsx React.DOM */
    var APP = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            );
        }
    });

    React.renderComponent(<APP />, document.body);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got the following error:

[image]

When I expand on the error:

[image]

Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update:

In the newer versions it is ([documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html))

```
ReactDOM.render(reactElement, domContainerNode)
```

---

It is should be `React.render` and not `React.renderComponent` as per [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.render)

The video you mentioned uses 0.8 and you are using 0.13.

From 0.12 `renderComponent` has been replaced with `render`