# Cannot render: React.renderComponent in my meteor app

Tags: meteor, reactjs

Hi there I just started making my meteor app with react(jsx) in webstorm and I can't seem to find out why my React component won't render no matter how much i search around.

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFvZydtmsxM) and this is the script in my html

```
<script type="text/jsx">
    /*** @jsx React.DOM */

    var APP = React.createClass({
        render:function(){
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>this is a app</h1>
                </div>
                )
        }
    });

    React.renderComponent(<APP />, document.getElementById('content'))
</script>
```

but when i run the meteor app I get [this in the browser](http://gyazo.com/0e0326c4ff7e4f4abcc48582249eeb4b)

**UPDATE: The problem ended up being that I needed to render my components in
my meteor document (in js) not in the jsx section of my html**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get started with ReactJS Hello World example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492023/how-to-get-started-with-reactjs-hello-world-example)

Comment: You might try: https://github.com/reactjs/react-meteor

Comment: Self closing tag's arn't working for me in webstorm, I am trying to do <APP></APP> but with no success. Everything else checks out

Comment: WebStorm doesn't do much with JSX syntax currently (and doesn't auto close tags). It's basically hands off and requires you to type the syntax exactly as you need it.

Comment: That kinda sucks, it still doesn't explain why the component won't render. It should work if i have a opening and closing tag.

Comment: This link gives you an idea whats wrong http://gyazo.com/cf852ec0e7e1cb23d41f4cc00a5d8337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like its just complaining about jsx and doesn't like the tags. Maybe try it without jsx for the renderComponent call?

```
    React.renderComponent(React.createElement(APP, null), document.getElementById('content'))
```

Otherwise, try converting all your jsx (including class definition) to native js:

```
var APP = React.createClass({displayName: "APP",
        render:function(){
            return (
                 React.createElement("div", null, 
                    React.createElement("h1", null, "this is a app")
                 )
                )
        }
    });

    React.renderComponent(React.createElement(APP, null), document.getElementById('content'))
```

You can use the handy [jsx compiler](http://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html) that Facebook provides

Answer (score 0):

You can try react-meteor, It lets you create the components using the reactMeteor class, and export them as a meteor blaze template making it very simple to re utilize.